# How to "move" Eigen::VectorXd s

Tags: c++, c++11, move, eigen

A commenter in a recent post of mine told me I need to utilize c++11 move-semantics better to deal with a bottleneck in my code. Below is a simplified version of what needs to be fixed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <vector>

void makeCopy(std::vector<Eigen::VectorXd> &oldV){
    int n = oldV.size();
    std::vector<Eigen::VectorXd> mandatoryCopy;
    mandatoryCopy.resize(n);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        mandatoryCopy[i] = oldV[i];
    }

    // swap the two
    oldV = mandatoryCopy;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // starting vector
    int len(1000);
    Eigen::VectorXd placeHolder(50);
    std::vector<Eigen::VectorXd> v(len, placeHolder);

    // copy it a bunch of times
    for(int iter = 0; iter < 1000; ++iter){
        std::cout << "iter: " << iter << "\n";
        makeCopy(v);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Question: inside the for loop of `makeCopy`, `oldV[i]`is an lvalue, so how could I do something like `mandatoryCopy[i]&& = oldV[i]`? This is the primary bottleneck, right? I'm thinking something like `mandatoryCopy[i]&& = std::move(oldV[i])`, but this obviously won't compile.

### Edit

As per @vsoftco's suggestion, I have tried

```
std::vector<Eigen::VectorXd> makeCopy2(std::vector<Eigen::VectorXd> oldV){

    int n = oldV.size();
    std::vector<Eigen::VectorXd> mandatoryCopy;
    mandatoryCopy.resize(n);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        mandatoryCopy[i] = oldV[i];
    }
    return mandatoryCopy;
}
```

but I find that it is slower. Both @vsoftco and @ggael have mentioned that it would be faster to return a modified copied argument, instead of copying again, and I agree, but I doubt that this is possible for my actual code. I could ask about this later, but it would be a separate question/thread.

Comment: Well it's slower because you now create 2 copies. Just use `oldV` directly inside your function, no need to make another copy. At function exit the argument is not going to be modified, as you pass it by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not looking at the right line. If one copy is mandatory, then you cannot get rid of it. Nonetheless, better avoid the for loop and right:

```
std::vector<Eigen::VectorXd> mandatoryCopy = oldV;
```

On the other hand, you can omit the second copy by replacing `oldV=mandatoryCopy` with:

```
std::swap(oldV,mandatoryCopy);
```

that will perform a cheap pointer exchange. You get:

```
void makeCopy(std::vector<Eigen::VectorXd> &oldV){
  std::vector<Eigen::VectorXd> V = oldV;
  // do something with V
  std::swap(oldV,V);
}
```

For the functional style, in your second example, you must directly play with the argument which is already a copy:

```
std::vector<Eigen::VectorXd> makeCopy2(std::vector<Eigen::VectorXd> V){
  // do something with V
  return V;
}
```

and call it with `v = makeCopy2(v);`.

Do not forget to compile with `-std=c++11` to get move semantic copies.

Finally, it might be better to pack your `vector<VectorXd>` within a `MatrixXd`. This will **dramatically** reduce the number of memory allocations:

```
void makeCopy3(MatrixXd &oldV){
  int n = oldV.cols();
  MatrixXd V = oldV;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    V.col(i) *= 0.99;
  }
  oldV.swap(V); // or oldV = std::move(V); with c++11 enabled
}
```