# how to copy a vector in std::vector<Eigen::vectorXd> to another vector in another std::vector<Eigen::vectorXd>

Tags: c++

how to copy a vector (Eigen::vectorXd) in `std::vector<Eigen::vectorXd>` to another vector (Eigen::vectorXd) in another `std::vector<Eigen::vectorXd>`

```
std::vector< Eigen::VectorXd > samples;
std::vector< Eigen::VectorXd > boea_samples;
```

I would like to do

```
samples[i] = boea_samples[i];
```

But it does not work and without error when compile. It just stops when run `samples[i] = boea_samples[i];`

Thanks!

Comment: Probably these lines are not the reason of your problem, because Eigen::VectorXd class has operator= implemented. This [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442748/how-to-move-eigenvectorxd-s) is quite similar and might help. Could you provide compiler error messages or full piece of code which doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigen only supports fixed size vectors being used in STL containers. Even then it is not straight forward. The Eigen library implement their own allocater for their objects. This causes that you need to take some extra steps when using Eigen objects in STL containers.

This is an example from the documentation Eigen:

```
#include<Eigen/StdVector>
/* ... */
std::vector<Eigen::Vector4f, Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Vector4f> >
```

What you see is that besides the data type also the allocater is specified as a template argument.

You can read more in this somewhat hidden chapter of the Eigen documentation:
https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStlContainers.html

Comment: `Eigen only supports fixed size vectors being used in STL containers.` I don't think this is true. I used both VectorXf and MatrixXf in std::vectors. The dynamic variants obviously don't store the actual data in the memory the std::vector allocated, but there shouldn't be any issue in storing the VectorXd element in a std::vector.

Comment: It could well be that the dynamic objects them self do not need those allocators. I can not find this in the documentation now. I think I was only using fixed size vectors and matrices hence I came across this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I kind of fixed it. The idea is that we need to give an initial size vectors that we can pass the value to the vectors.